# Encoded Characters in Query Parameters Crash Angular Client

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When a user requests a password reset, a reset url will be send by email:

https://example.com/reset-password?id=206dd3f4-8248-4e7a-bd90-16585a0cc165&code=CfDJ8KegIZmThRtPj1kp523h7xyoNB5wCUt%2BvSf7e53lGbvQoE7xagL4mnLODLy0v6WCC91fiPoN9TRreDVT8SJvDABKX5X3KG8LT1XZqqrlilWC5kbiTmWYKUfWju7DrsZ1DUuEvvJLAqNpbqI%2Fgkiu0vb3PGkinIbygMMBJufllU4TY5qcOjzQIQo06eNo1KR6L1lwT9Vap0TE5rr%2FuYIyt2lRIJQGk9pBUg2qQuiolDl4

This url consists of a user id and a generated token by Identity Core;

```
    [HttpPost("forgot")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword([FromBody]ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                return Ok();
            }

            var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
            var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"id", user.Id },
                {"token", token }
            };

            var callbackUrl = ResetPasswordCallbackLink(queryParams); // <--- Creates the url

            await _emailSender.SendResetPasswordAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

            _logger.LogInformation($"User: {model.Email} forgot password");

            return Ok();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

This token is crashing the client (Angular 6+) side because of the encoded characters in the token %2B (+) and %2F (/).

Without these encoded characters, the page renders perfectly and the parameters can be read with;

```
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('token');
```

**UPDATE**

Navigating to a random existing page like /login?id=123%2B will also generate a 'InternalError: too much recursion' by RxJs. http://prntscr.com/mrspvf So it probably is an architectural issue?

Comment: Do you have any way to process the url (replace charaters) before the url is mailed to the users?

Comment: Yes it is being processed, when clicking on the link, the %2F and %2B are shown in the url and makes the client side crash. FYI, when doing this through postman, I can succesfuly change the password

Comment: Can you show where you are processing this parameter? It should work fine, for example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yd51e9

Comment: @Rafael: I mean, do you have the possibility in the backend code to replace the characters that make the angular crash?

Comment: @mortb I do, but when replacing the encoded characters (%2F = / and %2B = +) by hand for example keeps crashing the client-side,

Comment: @DavidG 'InternalError: too much recursion' I have used the method shown in your stackblitz

Comment: Then you need to show us some code that exhibits this error or we can't help. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you have the code for `ResetPasswordCallbackLink(...)`? Can you include it?

Comment: @mortb at the client side? the callback url is created server-side, see my code addition

Comment: Yes, in the server side. Maybe if you "double escape" the url so that % becomes %% in the server side before the url is send in the mail it will not crash the client side when the user clicks it. When the code is returned to the server side, you may add code that substitutes %% with % before processing.